# Expand a curve to a circular contour plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Context: Two sets of data, one is the radius, r, and the other is the velocity, v. v can be positive and negative. The following code

`p1=ListLogLogPlot[Table[{r[[i]],v[[i]]},{i,1,number_of_data}]];
p2=ListLogLogPlot[Table[{r[[i]],-v[[i]]},{i,1,number_of_data}],PlotStyle->{Red}];
Show[p1,p2]`

is used to give a curve, with positive and negative v both plotted in log-log coordinates.

Question: How to draw a circular, contour-like plot, with Log[r] as the distance to the center of the circle, and the velocities (Log[v]) shown as different, but continuously varying colors, according to v's sign and magnitude?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `DensityPlot` function:

```
v[r_] := Sin[r]*r^2
DensityPlot[v[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

You can deal with the tabular data in two ways. You can either interpolate and use the interpolating function as above or you may use a `ListDensityPlot` function:

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[With[{r = RandomReal[{0, 4}], t = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}, 
    {r Cos[t], r Sin[t], v[r]}], {10^4}]]
```

I hope this helps.